# web application behavior in kubernetes environment

Tags: go, kubernetes

while deploying application [ deployment xml file ] in kubernetes, if some property is not provided [ either secret or configmapref ] then kuberenetes gives containererror status and it waits till we provide correct configuration. that is if I create exact name of secret or configmapref then automatically it will start.

in my case, I have one webapplication which requires yaml file. if there are errors in that yaml file my application has to wait similar way and once he provides correctly then it will start with other components.

[ I can do this waiting for long period in while loop with certain time interval , any other alternative way kubernetes is helping us ]
There are certain validations I am doing on this yaml file, correctness checks like validating url or email all those and when I decided if those are wrong, wait till user corrects it.
Can we do this using kubernetes ?

Comment: Use a configmap. Mount the file from the configmap, and fail if file is wrong. The pod will retry for a while, and if you deploy the correct file it will pick it up and start correctly.

Comment: Thank you, my case is little different, first I need to fetch that configMap, validate in my application and then  I will decide if values are proper I need to continue, if not I need to wait till user corrects it. so is that possible simlar way which you mentioned above @BurakSerdar

Comment: Elaborate more aboot the usecase. If info is wrong then let it fail and just redeploy when  new correct information is entered. Also there is initcontainer which can be used  to check  these validation

Comment: If you do the validation at startup time as @BurakSerdar suggests, and your application exits if it's invalid, it will go into CrashLoopBackOff state, and Kubernetes will do the waiting for you.  It won't be synched to the ConfigMap, though, so you may need to manually restart the pod if you make a change (or wait a while longer).